# ¿Se puede saber cuanto son los números pares e impares de N numero hasta M numero, solo con funciones sin usar ciclos?

Tags: c, funciones, condiciones

Quiero saber si se puede obtener cuantos números pares e impares hay en un rango de n numero a m número, ejemplo del 1 al 5. O sea 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, en ese rango hay 2 pares y 3 impares. Esto es bastante sencillo con un ciclo, pero no puedo usar ciclos, solo con funciones y condiciones "if", intente hacerlo con funciones recursivas que es lo mas parecido aun ciclo pero no logro obtener la cantidad de cada uno. intente con un contador pero no salió bien, a ver si alguien me puede ayudar con un código desde 0. EL mío lo borre, solo deseo ver si se puede hacer así en lenguaje C. Saludos.

Comment: Seguro que si!!! pero mostranos tus intentos, asi podemos contarte que hiciste mal.. si no, parece que queres que alguien haga el ejercicio por vos...

Comment: Exacto quiero ver como otros lo hacen el que yo hice lo borre jajaja

Comment: Es que debés mostrar un [repro] de lo que intentaste hasta el momento, y el problema _específico_ que tuviste. [es.so] no es un servicio de código: demostrá que estás haciendo el esfuerzo en resolver tu problema. Sino, tal como te han dicho, pareciera que querés que hagan el ejercicio por vos. [**Aquí no hacemos tareas**](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4320) y pareciera que [no intentaste nada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/).

Comment: No necesitas una función. Si el rango es de números consecutivos, claramente la mitad son pares y la mitad impares. Si los 2 extremos son pares, tienes un par más y si son impares, tienes un impar más.

Comment: De hecho el problema indica usar funciones por eso no uso ciclos porque seria sencillo. Pero ya tengo la idea, gracias. @Mateo

Comment: @padaleiana Ya lo comente y dije que el código lo borre así de simple, además no es mi tarea, solo es un problema de prueba y quiero ver como alguien lo hacia, pero si le molesta tanto mejor no me comente, que yo sepa en esta plataforma no me restringe eso o si?. Saludos.

Comment: Ya ves que la pregunta terminó cerrada por no ser más específico :) Y no es molestia, es cuidar que el sitio tenga preguntas claras y de calidad. De eso se trata [es.so].